# How to show multiple feature info on a map click of multiple layers displayed using geoserver

Tags: javascript, html, openlayers-3, geoserver

```js
var element = document.getElementById('popup');
var popup = new ol.Overlay({
          element: element,
          positioning: 'bottom-center',

          stopEvent: false
      });
      map.addOverlay(popup);
var Source_ATM =
        new ol.source.TileWMS({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/BMC/wms',
        params: {
            'LAYERS': 'BMC:atm',
            'VERSION': '1.1.0',
            'FORMAT': 'image/png',
            'TILED': true
        },
        id:"atm",
        serverType:'geoserver'
        });


    var Layer_ATM = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: Source_ATM,

    });

    Layer_ATM.setVisible(false);

    //block_boundary Layer
    var Source_BlockBoundary =
        new ol.source.TileWMS({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/BMC/wms?',
        params: {
            'LAYERS': 'BMC:block_boundary',
            'VERSION': '1.1.0',
            'FORMAT': 'image/png',
            'TILED': true
        },
        id:"block_boundary",
        serverType:'geoserver'
    });

    var Layer_block_boundary = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: Source_BlockBoundary,

    });

    Layer_block_boundary.setVisible(false);
    function featureinfoFun() {

                  map.on('singleclick', function (evt) {

                      var view = map.getView();
                      var viewResolution = view.getResolution();

                      var source = Layer_block_boundary.getSource();
                      //var source2=Layer_test.getSource();

                      var url = source.getGetFeatureInfoUrl(
                        evt.coordinate, viewResolution, view.getProjection(),
                        { 'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/html', 'FEATURE_COUNT': 50 });

                      if (url) {
                          var coordinate = evt.coordinate;
                          popup.setPosition(coordinate);
                          $(element).popover("destroy");
                          $(element).popover({
                              'placement': 'top',
                              'html': true,
                              'content': '<iframe style="width: 105%;"seamless src="' + url + '"></iframe>'

                          });

                          $(element).popover('show');
                          $(element).css('display', 'block');
                          //$(element).popup.classList.toggle('show');
                          //$(element).popup.close();
                      }
                  });
            }
```

```css
    .ol-popup {
            position: absolute;
            background-color: white;
            -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2));
            filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2));
            padding: 15px;
            border-radius: 10px;
            border: 1px solid #cccccc;
            bottom: 12px;
            left: -50px;
            min-width: 280px;
          }
          .ol-popup:after, .ol-popup:before {
            top: 100%;
            border: solid transparent;
            content: " ";
            height: 0;
            width: 0;
            position: absolute;
            pointer-events: none;
          }
          .ol-popup:after {
            border-top-color: white;
            border-width: 10px;
            left: 48px;
            margin-left: -10px;
          }
          .ol-popup:before {
            border-top-color: #cccccc;
            border-width: 11px;
            left: 48px;
            margin-left: -11px;
          }
          .ol-popup-closer {
            text-decoration: none;
            position: absolute;
            top: 2px;
            right: 8px;
          }
          .ol-popup-closer:after {
            content: "✖";
          }
```

```html
    <div id="map1" class="map" style="position: fixed; height:100%; margin-top: 28px;">

                    <!--div class="ol-toggle-options ol-unselectable"><a title="Toggle options toolbar" onClick="toggleControlPanel()" href="#toggle"></a></div-->

                    <div id="popup" class="ol-overlay-container" style="width:200px;height: 0px;">
                    <a href="#" id="popup-closer" class="ol-popup-closer"></a>
                        <div id="popup-content" class="popover-content"></div>
```

This is my code. Please help me to display feature information of both of the layers. please help me with code. I want to show multiple layers and when i click on a layer and another layer it will display the attribute information coming from geoserver for both of the layers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show information from both layers you either need to make **two** `getFeatureInfo` requests (one for each layer). Or, you can combine the two layers in the request by setting the `LAYERS` & `QUERY_LAYERS` parameters to be a comma separated list of layer names (if you are specifying styles then you will also need to add both style names to the `STYLES` parameter).

The easiest way to do this is to add `LAYERS` & `QUERY_LAYERS` to the param block when calling `getFeatureInfoUrl`

Comment: Can you please help me with some coding example? it will be helpful. Thanks a lot.